# Simulating rbinom 100,000 times and finding proportions

Tags: r

So I want to simulate 200 observations of binary random numbers whose value is 1 with a 60% probability and 0 with a 40% probability, and calculate the proportion of 1s. Repeat the simulation 100,000 times and find out how many times the proportion is smaller than 0.55

So far I know I need to have `rbinom(200,1,.6)` and probably a for loop somewhere

What I've been able to write is this

```
x=numeric(100000)
for(i in 1:100000){
x[i]=rbinom(200,1,.6)}
```

But everytime I do it just doesn't work. Also, how could I know how many times the proportion is smaller than .55?

Comment: You seem to be trying to store 200 observations into a single slot. Perhaps you want to store a numerical summary of those observations? Also -- look into `replicate` rather than a loop.

Comment: I think I just want to see out of 100,000 tests of the rbinom, how many of those tests give the number 1 more than or equal to 55% of the 200 observations. So i guess the thresold would be 110/200. Meaning how many out of 100,000 tests of the rbinom will give me 110 ones at least.

Comment: So you want something like `x[i]=mean(rbinom(200,1,.6))` and then to compare those means with 0.55 (or, better yet, the equivalent with `replicate`)

Comment: Try `x <- replicate(100000, sum(rbinom(200, 1, .6))`. The resulting `x` should be a vector of 100,000 sums of the 200 observations. Then `sum(x <= 110)` is the number of times you got less than or equal to .55.

Comment: Also suggest you read up on the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

```r
set.seed(1L)
n <- 100000
thresh <- 110

sum(replicate(n, sum(rbinom(200,1,.6))) >= thresh) # 93420
```

Answer (score 0):

To get number of times proportion is smaller than 0.55 you can do :

```
n <- 10000
sum(replicate(n, mean(rbinom(200,1,.6)) < 0.55))
```

To calculate the probability we can use `mean`.

```
mean(replicate(n, mean(rbinom(200,1,.6)) < 0.55))
```